# What is this に in 知恵に挑戦する

Tags: grammar, transitivity

As usual, I'm having trouble with this particle. Here's the sentence:

> 誰にでも見られるところに堂々と張り出し、私たちの知恵**に**挑戦する。

I don't understand. I would personally have written "私たちの知恵を挑戦する。". How is に effective here? Or is it one of those special verbs that can use に ?

Comment: 挑戦する or 挑む are intransitive and equivalent to 行く in terms of case relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This に has the nuance of the meaning of 対して, it may be close to "to" and "for". Dictionaries say 動作・作用の行われる対象・相手を表す.

We generally say to ～に挑戦する, not ～を挑戦する. Other examples are に近づく, に乗る, に行く, etc. Intransitive verbs don't take を as the object marker.

Of course, transitive verbs take を as the object marker as in 車を運転する.

Further, direct object takes を and indirect object takes に as in 彼にボールを投げた.

Answer (score 0):

「挑戦{ちょうせん}する」 is an intransitive verb; therefore, it cannot take 「を」 as the object marker.  It takes 「に」 instead.

Thus, 「私達の知恵に挑戦する」 means "***to challenge our intelligence***".

(The first part of your sentence 「誰にでもところに」 makes no sense, so I would not attempt at translating the whole sentence.  You must have miscoppied that part.)

Comment: Haha, sorry. I will edit. If it is intransitive, can it take が ? In fact I'm a bit confused because I often see する verbs with the を particle.

Comment: I will be honest; You sound very confused about basic grammar points.  Transitivity of a verb has nothing to do with the verb being a suru-verb or not.  It just so happens that 挑戦する is intransitive.  You need to memorize it one by one.  The same goes for English; There is no secret formula.  It is just part of language acquisition, mother tongue or foreign lingo.  「が」 has nothing to do with verb transitivity.  If you see a が right in front of 挑戦する, that would be the subject marker.  「私がスノボに挑戦する。」= "I'll challenge snowboarding."